# Time.timeScale not working Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

These are two scripts that are using time.timeScale. One uses it to stop the game when we run out of time and the other uses it to pause the game when escape is pressed. GameControlScript is runs perfect except Time.timeScale. Gameover GUI shows but the game still continue behind the GUI.

```
//This script is for game mechanics, this script controls point system, gameover, score, total time in the game

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameControlScript : MonoBehaviour {

//  public GUISkin skin;
float timeRemaining = 10; //time left at start of game
float timeExtension = 3f; //time added after powerup is collected
float timeDeduction = 2f; //time deducted after obsticle is hit
float totalTimeElapsed = 0; //time you last in game
float score=0f; //player's score
public bool isGameOver = false; //flag to check if game is over
public AudioSource GameOverSound; //sound play at the end game


public Text ScoreBoard;
public Text FinalScore;
public Text GameTimeLeft;
public GameObject GameOverPanel;


 void Start(){
    Time.timeScale = 1;  // set the time scale to 1, to start the game world. This is needed if you restart the game from the game over menu
}

 void Update () { 



    if(isGameOver) //check if game is over
        return; //if game is not over don't do anything (it sends control to Update and doesn't let it excute code down there)



        totalTimeElapsed += Time.deltaTime; //adding amount of time passed in totalTimeElapsed variable
        score = totalTimeElapsed * 100; //multipling totalTimeElapsed with 100 to create score of player
        timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime; //subtracting passing time from timeRemaining

        GameTimeLeft.text = "TIME LEFT: " + ((int)timeRemaining).ToString ();
        ScoreBoard.text = "SCORE: " + ((int)score).ToString ();

    if (timeRemaining <= 0) { //check if timeRemaining is less or equal to zero


        Time.timeScale = 0;

        GameOverPanel.SetActive (true);
        FinalScore.text = "YOUR SCORE: " + ((int)score).ToString ();

        isGameOver = true; //if it is less or equal to zero game is over
        GameOverSound.Play (); //play gameover sound

    }//end if

    }//end Update
```

This is Pause Script:

```
//This Script pause the game when escape is pressed
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class PauseMenuScript : MonoBehaviour

{

public GUISkin myskin; //custom GUIskin reference

public string levelToLoad;// name of level to load

public bool paused = false;  //flag to check if the game is paused

public AudioSource MenuClickSound;




private void Start()

{

    Time.timeScale=1; //Set the timeScale back to 1 for Restart option to work

}



private void Update()

{



    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) ) //check if Escape key/Back key is pressed

    {

        if (paused)

            paused = false; //unpause the game if already

        else

            paused = true; //pause the game if not paused

    }

    if(paused)

        Time.timeScale = 0; //set the timeScale to 0 so that all the procedings are halte

    else

        Time.timeScale = 1; //set it back to 1 on unpausing the game



}



private void OnGUI()

{

    GUI.skin=myskin;  //use the custom GUISkin

    if (paused){   


        //Shows text PAUSED when game is paused
        GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width/4, Screen.height/4, Screen.width/2, Screen.height/2), "PAUSED");



        //Draws button Resume and resume game when it is pressed
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/4+10, Screen.height/4+Screen.height/10+10, Screen.width/2-20, Screen.height/10), "RESUME")){
            MenuClickSound.Play ();
            paused = false;

        }
        //Draws button Restart and restart game when it is pressed
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/4+10, Screen.height/4+2*Screen.height/10+10, Screen.width/2-20, Screen.height/10), "RESTART")){
            MenuClickSound.Play ();
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel); // load already loaded level

        }


        //Draws button Main Menu and takes user to main menu when it is pressed
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/4+10, Screen.height/4+3*Screen.height/10+10, Screen.width/2-20, Screen.height/10), "MAIN MENU")){
            MenuClickSound.Play ();
            Application.LoadLevel(levelToLoad); // name of the scene which has to be load in order to go to main menu

        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work"....You need to explain what you mean by that

Comment: Maybe because `timeRemaining <= 0` is never true?

Comment: If you have two scripts both mucking with `Time.timeScale` *one* of them wins.

Comment: @z3nth10n timeRemaining<=0 is true. when time runs out and the game is over, it becomes true. It is supposed to show the game over GUI and stop any activity happening in the background. but timescale doesn't work. it doesn't stop anything. the game still runs in the background.

Comment: @Draco18s both scripts are not running at the same time. if I press escape the pause script will run and if the time runs out in the game it will stop everything and will show GUI of gameover and final score. But timescale doesn't work in this script but runs in pause script if I press escape.

Comment: @Programmer I debug.log it and it prints the statement after Time.timeScale. I also printed the timescale value and it says 0. but the game doesn't stop. I have another script which is for pause if escape is pressed and time stops if I press esc.

Comment: I'm just going to reitterate my previous comment. Only one script win this fight. And as you haven't shown that other script, I'm making a pretty good assumption about what it does and how. My prediction is md5: `fa7a23e861d55b872a1024bab37b476f`. Post your pause script and I'll reveal the text of it.

Comment: @Draco18s edited the question and added pause script.

Comment: I was right. Here's my prediction https://pastebin.com/gY4Rp04M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your pause script which is causing the issue.
When your game is running paused is set to false, so it resets timescale to 1 in update so when gameover is called, paused is still false.

1. you need to make sure pause script isn't running when you load gameover. or
2. just set paused value to true so it will work and won't reset time.timescale to 1.

[image]

Comment: But i guess your issue is, once gameover is loaded, your game is still running in background right?

It is because time.timescale is 1 instead 0 so you need to correct that.

Comment: @SKJ DING DING DING you and Draco18s are right. Thank you!

Comment: @Draco18s Thank you. I disabled the pause script and it works. debug log the else statement in pause script. turn out it is doing what SKJ said.

Comment: ...or [what I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264053/time-timescale-not-working-unity/50267654?noredirect=1#comment87547688_50264053)...

Comment: @NoorulainArain
I am glad it helped.
Please accept it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

once you set timescale to 0, all subsequent calls to time deltaTime will return zero (so timeRemaining will not change). Try using Time.unscaledDeltaTime instead

Comment: timeRemaining works fine. The code in it works great. it's only the Time.timeScale that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

`Time.timeScale` works fine.

Unity, unreal or other game engines (programs, apps) doesn't have some "pause" as you think. To freeze some objects behind GUI, you must multiply, for example, moveSpeed to deltaTime.

Example:

```
public class CharacterController:MonoBehaviour{
    public float moveSpeed = 3.5f; 
    void Update(){
       transform.position += Vector3.Right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

When `Time.timeScale = 0;` then `Time.deltaTime` will return 0 and your object will be "freezed".

Answer (score 0):

```
 void Start()
        {`
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
```

This works for me. Thanks!